# Change recorded value in one dataframe using another dataframe while keeping all other values in the record constant (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I create a two dataframes called applesdf and applesaucedf to show columns named id, item, price and location. My goal is to use the ID to change the name of the item in applesdf while keeping all other values (price and location) in the instance constant.

For example:

```
applesdf = {'ID': [1],
        'Item': ['Apple'],
        'Price': [2],
        'Location':[1001]
        }
```

Apples dataframe:

| ID | Item | Price | Location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple | 2 | 1001 |

```
applesaucedf = {'ID': [1],
        'Item': ['Applesauce'],
        'Price': [3],
        'Location':[1002]
        }
```

AppleSauce dataframe:

| ID | Item | Price | Location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Applesauce | 3 | 1002 |

Now we just want to use the ID column to change the item name while keeping everything else constant. My hopeful output:

| ID | Item | Price | Location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Applesauce | 2 | 1001 |

**I know a for loop using df.loc works for this but let's imagine we have thousands of rows of data. A for loop would obviously then not be optimal. Is there any documentation available for functions that would allow for this while working with large datasets?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a map of ID --> Item from applesaucedf and use the map on appledf

```
mapper = applesaucedf.set_index('ID')['Item'].to_dict()
print(mapper)

{1: 'Applesauce'}

applesdf['Item'] = applesdf['ID'].map(mapper)
print(applesdf)

    ID  Item    Price   Location
0   1   Applesauce  2   1001
```